# Filter/display elements based on selected category

Tags: django, django-views

I am still very new to Django and I stucked with one Issue. I have built Models as defined below:

```
# models.py

from django.db import models
from bifrost.models import CustomUser
from django.urls import reverse

# Create your models here.


# Model Projektu
class Project(models.Model):
    PROJECT_TYPE = (
        ('Scrum', 'Scrum'),
        ('Kanban', 'Kanban'),
    )
    project_key = models.CharField(max_length=8)
    project_name = models.CharField(max_length=160)
    project_type = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=PROJECT_TYPE)
    project_lead = models.ForeignKey(CustomUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    project_date_created = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)


    def __str__(self):
        return self.project_name

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('project-detail', args=[str(self.id)])

class Issue(models.Model):
    ISSUE_PRIORITY = (
        ('C', 'Critical'),
        ('H', 'High'),
        ('M', 'Medium'),
        ('L', 'Low'),
    )
    issue_type = models.TextField(default='Issue', editable=False)
    issue_id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    issue_date_created = models.DateField()
    issue_date_updated = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    issue_project = models.ForeignKey(Project, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    issue_title = models.TextField()
    issue_description = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    issue_epic = models.ForeignKey(Epic, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    issue_sprint = models.ForeignKey(Sprint, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    issue_priority = models.CharField(max_length=8, choices=ISSUE_PRIORITY)
    issue_assignee = models.ForeignKey(CustomUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='assignees', null=True, blank=True) 
    issue_author = models.ForeignKey(CustomUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='authors') 
    issue_remaining_estimate = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True) # w minutach
    issue_time_logged = models.IntegerField(default='0') 
    issue_attachment = models.FileField(null=True, blank=True)
    issue_backlog_order = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
```

Now I would like to display list of Issues, that relates to selected Project. I read about creating a dictionary in view or proper queryset, but no solution works for me :( How can I get dynamically which context (project) user selected and based on that filter issues properly?

## views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404
from django.views.generic import ListView, DetailView
from .models import Project, Issue, Epic
from django.views.generic.edit import CreateView, UpdateView, DeleteView
from django.views.generic import TemplateView
from django.urls import reverse_lazy


# Create your views here.

class ProjectListView(ListView):
  model = Project
  template_name = 'project-list.html'
  context_object_name = 'projects_list'

class ProjectBacklogView(DetailView):
  template_name = 'project-backlog.html'
  context_object_name = 'backlog'
```

## urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from .views import ProjectListView, ProjectDetailView, ProjectCreateView, ProjectUpdateView, ProjectDeleteView, ProjectBacklogView

urlpatterns = [
  path('<int:pk>/delete', ProjectDeleteView.as_view(), name='project-delete'),
  path('<int:pk>/edit/', ProjectUpdateView.as_view(), name='project-edit'),
  path('new/', ProjectCreateView.as_view(), name='project-create'),
  path('<int:pk>/', ProjectDetailView.as_view(), name='project-detail'),
  path('<int:pk>/backlog', ProjectBacklogView.as_view(), name='project-backlog'),
  path('', ProjectListView.as_view(), name='project'),
 ]
```

Many thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: I suppose `ProjectBacklogView` has as `model = Project`?

Comment: Yes indeed, however my previous mistake was that I tried to take as a basis `model = Issue` @WillemVanOnsem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Now I would like to display list of Issues, that relates to selected Project.

You can simply put that logic in template of the backlog (`project-backlog.html`). You can access the queryset containing the related issues with `backlog.issue_set.all()`, so in your template you can render the related issues for example with:

```
<!-- project-backlog.html -->
{% for issue in backlog.issue_set.all %}
{{ issue.name }}
{% endfor %}
```

Here we thus iterate over the `Issue`s related to the `backlog` object, and we render the `issue.name`. Of course we can make it more sophisticated, and render it as a table. For example:

```
<!-- project-backlog.html -->
<table>
<tr><th>Name</th></tr>
{% for issue in backlog.issue_set.all %}
<tr><td>{{ issue.name }}</td></tr>
{% endfor %}
</table>
```

the above is of course still a draft, and it will probably require some editing to generate something more visually appealing.

Comment: Thank you very much @Willem, it works! I didn't even think about putting filter logic to template directly, I tried to do it via views.py

Comment: @yorgwarez: well for more sophisticated filtering, that is definitely the way to go (for example if you want to do extra filtering on the type of issues). In that case one typically overrides the `get_context_data`, and adds some extra variables ffor template rendering.